# Confirming PayPal payment using Parse.com cloud code

Tags: curl, paypal, parse-platform

In order to confirm payments I need an access_token which expires every 8 hours so I need to fetch a new access token with cloud code before I try to verify a payment.

I am trying to use a httpRequest:

```
function requestAccessToken(response){
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language' : 'en_US'
            },
            body: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                var res = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
                response.success(res.access_token);
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error('requestAccessToken failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

To do the following curl ([from docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)):

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "{client-ID}:{secret}" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to add the "{client-ID}:{secret}" to the httpRequest.

using `url: 'https://'+clientId+':'+secret+'@api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'` results in a 500 server response.

Any Ideas how I can get an access token to verify the payments?

Comment: Do you have more details on the error you get? Also, have you tried to do the curl command to verify that you get something there?

Comment: If you are using node, you might want to take a look at the [officially supported node sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs) or have a look at how it does [authorization](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/blob/master/lib/api.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an authorization header

```
      Authorization: Basic < {client-ID}:{secret}" encoded base64> (e.g. QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==)
```